# Terraform conditions : How to have a multiple values in case of False condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to have two urls in case if my environment is nonprod(sit,uat,dev) and my application is Techno, otherwise only one url. In order to do that, I have made every string into a list here, so that the returned value is consistent. Otherwise I get `The true and false result expressions must have consistent types` error.

Now, with this, I am getting this error :

`Inappropriate value for attribute callback_urls: element 0: string required.`

How to achieve this ?

```
callback_urls = [var.target_infra == "prod" ? (var.application_name == "techno" ? ["https://${local.domain_name}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/auth"] : ["https://${local.domain_name}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/setup/auth"]) : (var.application_name == "techno" ? ["https://${local.domain_name}.${var.environment}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/auth", "http://localhost:3000/auth"] : ["https://${local.domain_name}.${var.environment}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/setup/auth"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT answers :)

```
callback_urls = concat(
  var.target_infra == "prod" ?
    (var.application_name == "techno" ?
      ["https://${local.domain_name}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/auth"] :
      ["https://${local.domain_name}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/setup/auth"]
    ) :
    (var.application_name == "techno" ?
      [
        "https://${local.domain_name}.${var.environment}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/auth",
        "http://localhost:3000/auth"
      ] :
      ["https://${local.domain_name}.${var.environment}.${local.pe_subdomain_name[var.target_infra]}/setup/auth"]
    )
  )
```